# Simplification - Boolean Algebra using DeMorgan law

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Can somebody please help me simplify this expression using DeMorgan law.
>
> $\lnot{(A\land B)}+\lnot{(\lnot{A}\land B)}$
>
> Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I solved it using a truth table, it simplifies to $\lnot{(A \land B)}$. I'm asked to solve it using DeMorgan law.

Comment: But it simplifies to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present for the day:

$\overline{AB}+\overline{{\bar A}B} = \bar{A} + \bar{B} + A + \bar{B} = A + \bar{A} +\bar{B}= 1+\bar{B} = 1$

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got that too, but since I got the solution from my Professor, saying that the expression simplifies to ¬(A∧B), I thought my solution was wrong.

Comment: It is tautology